# Does touch attack ignore any armor bonuses?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, sneak-attack, touch-attacks, incorporeal

Reading the [touch attack](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm) description it says that it ignores any armor bonus. Does this mean they also ignore magical properties of the armor?

Example:

Does this mean that a creature attacking with touch attacks (e.g. incorporeal creature) can do critical hits on a creature wearing an armor with [heavy fortification](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicArmor.htm)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

That text means that touch attacks ignore all bonuses to Armor Class with type “armor”. But that explanation is misleadingly incomplete.

You might have noticed that nearly all bonuses in 3.5 are expressed as “+X *foo* bonus to *bar*. This is a key balance change from 3.0: bonuses with the same type (“foo”) don’t stack (with one or two specific exceptions that do stack, because reasons). Wearing armor gives you an *armor* bonus to AC (and a shield gives you a *shield* bonus, and most-but-not-all magic items give you a *deflection* bonus, etc).

Making it slightly more confusing, magic armor has an *enhancement* bonus, which is not actually applied to your AC, it is applied to your armor’s *armor* bonus, which then applies to your AC. (Quick side note; this is why stuff that **increases** a natural armor bonus is much better than stuff that **gives** a natural armor bonus.)

Because that’s not confusing at all.

Next problem: there are three kinds of AC: regular, touch, and flat-footed. “Regular” is just your normal armor class. Add up the highest bonus of each type and you’re done.

Flat-footed represents how hard it is to hurt you when you can’t move out of the way. If you shoot an arrow at a guy in plate while he’s asleep, there’s a good chance that he’ll be unharmed. You apply AC bonuses that are from being hard to hurt, like Armor, Natural Armor, and Luck, but not ones that come from moving out of the way, like DEX and Dodge.

Finally, touch AC. Thinking of the big guy in plate again, you can imagine a cleric slapping him more easily than a gymnast in body tights, even if the plate guy might normally be harder to hurt. Touch AC is literally just how hard it is to touch you. You apply AC bonuses that are from being hard to hit, like DEX, Dodge, and luck (again), but not from being hard to hurt, like Armor, Natural Armor, etc.

So. Specifically on your question, ignoring Armor bonus to AC means you add up the appropriate bonuses, but don’t add any *Armor* bonuses. That’s all. If your armor also plays your theme song (or whatever) it has no effect on that. But what you (probably) need is to calculate your touch AC, not just ignore armor bonuses. The specific rule there is:

> When you are the target of a touch attack, your AC doesn’t include any armor bonus, shield bonus, or natural armor bonus. All other modifiers, such as your size modifier, Dexterity modifier, and deflection bonus (if any) apply normally.

Comment: "That text means that touch attacks ignore all bonuses to Armor Class with type “armor”." touch ac also doesn't include natural armour and shield and stuff.  "That text means that touch attacks ignore certain bonuses to armor class (armor, natural armor, and shield)" would be a lot less misleading.

Comment: This is a great rundown of how this nonsense works. Fantastic answer.

Comment: @user2754 I disagree. fectin’s statement is entirely correct, it’s just incomplete—touch attacks _do_ ignore all bonuses to AC with type “armor.” They just _also_ ignore bonuses of some other types, too. But it makes sense not to get into that in that sentence because armor bonuses are the ones that are relevant to the point being made at that time; introducing other complications that aren’t immediately relevant just complicates things. The answer can—and does—get into those other bonuses that touch attacks ignore later.

Comment: Would be a better answer without all the editorializing.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile better for who? I love 3.5; it’s my favorite system by far. I love is that it is complex enough to produce emergent results and rewards system knowledge. I love less how that same complexity can make it very unapproachable for new players. This is clearly a new-player question. And it’s a very reasonable one, given that the interactions are legitimately confusing. So I editorialized both the make the answer less formal and to signal that their confusion is valid. If I were responding to an expert asking about esoterica, a neutral tone might be better. So again: better for who?

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile nothing is better without editorializing.

Comment: @KRyan people using this site for a quick answer will assume from that first sentence that touch attacks only remove the 'armor' bonus from AC, specifically, that one box on the default character sheet (some may include shields in that due to the linguistic commingling of 'shield' as a subset of 'armour').  My source on this is playing with new players recently extensively and seeing exactly this thing happen like a dozen times.  People lately read things _very_ literally and also only skim the very top of answers/articles, _I don't know why_.

Comment: @KRyan this question is for newer players to 3.5e as it's not something someone experienced with the system would generally think of.  Ergo i'd expect to see the same behaviour i've seen in new players to other systems (5e, fate, wod) recently and thus I recommend changing the first sentence to be complete in itself even if you later unpack and explain why and whatfors etc.

Comment: @user2754 I disagree—but if you think there are problems with this answer, arguing about them in these comments is not the appropriate solution. Rather, you should be authoring _your own_ answer. It’s quite acceptable to have two answers with competing methods of explaining the same details.